# Why does enzyme wrapper doesn't find a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have these dev dependencies installed:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.6",
    "jest-enzyme": "7.1.2"
  },
```

This is my test code:

```js
const onClickSpy = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <MessageItem
      message={{ message: "testmessage", table: "infotable" }}
      deleteMessageFromTable={onClickSpy}
    />
  );
```

I have a wrapper which contains the following:

```html
<div class="MuiPaper-root-7 MuiPaper-elevation8-17 MuiPaper-rounded-8 MuiCard-root-6">
  <div class="MuiCardContent-root-34">
    <p class="MuiTypography-root-35 MuiTypography-body1-44 MuiTypography-colorTextSecondary-68 MuiTypography-gutterBottom-62 MessageItem-title-5">
      testmessage
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="MuiCardActions-root-71">
    <button
      class="MuiButtonBase-root-100 MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73"
      tabindex="0"
      type="button"
      id="button-messageitem-1"
    >
      <span class="MuiButton-label-75">Clear</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does `wrapper.find("#button-messageitem-1");` not find the button?

The output from `console.log(wrapper.debug());` is:

```html
<WithStyles(Button) id="button-messageitem-1" size="small" className="MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" onClick={[Function: onClick]}>
        <Button id="button-messageitem-1" size="small" className="MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" onClick={[Function: onClick]} classes={{...}} color="default" component="button" disabled={false} disableFocusRipple={false} fullWidth={false} mini={false} type="button" variant="text">
          <WithStyles(ButtonBase) className="MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" disabled={false} focusRipple={true} focusVisibleClassName="MuiButton-focusVisible-93" id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]} component="button" type="button">
            <ButtonBase className="MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" disabled={false} focusRipple={true} focusVisibleClassName="MuiButton-focusVisible-93" id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]} component="button" type="button" classes={{...}} centerRipple={false} disableRipple={false} disableTouchRipple={false} tabIndex="0">
              <button className="MuiButtonBase-root-100 MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" onBlur={[Function (anonymous)]} onFocus={[Function (anonymous)]} onKeyDown={[Function (anonymous)]} onKeyUp={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseDown={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseLeave={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseUp={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchEnd={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchMove={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchStart={[Function (anonymous)]} onContextMenu={[Function (anonymous)]} tabIndex="0" type="button" disabled={false} id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]}>
                <span className="MuiButton-label-75">
                  Clear
                </span>
                <NoSsr defer={false} fallback={{...}}>
                  <WithStyles(TouchRipple) innerRef={[Function (anonymous)]} center={false}>
                    <TouchRipple center={false} classes={{...}}>
                      <TransitionGroup component="span" enter={true} exit={true} className="MuiTouchRipple-root-103" childFactory={[Function: childFactory]}>
                        <span className="MuiTouchRipple-root-103" />
                      </TransitionGroup>
                    </TouchRipple>
                  </WithStyles(TouchRipple)>
                </NoSsr>
              </button>
            </ButtonBase>
          </WithStyles(ButtonBase)>
        </Button>
      </WithStyles(Button)>
      <Button id="button-messageitem-1" size="small" className="MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" onClick={[Function: onClick]} classes={{...}} color="default" component="button" disabled={false} disableFocusRipple={false} fullWidth={false} mini={false} type="button" variant="text">
        <WithStyles(ButtonBase) className="MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" disabled={false} focusRipple={true} focusVisibleClassName="MuiButton-focusVisible-93" id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]} component="button" type="button">
          <ButtonBase className="MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" disabled={false} focusRipple={true} focusVisibleClassName="MuiButton-focusVisible-93" id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]} component="button" type="button" classes={{...}} centerRipple={false} disableRipple={false} disableTouchRipple={false} tabIndex="0">
            <button className="MuiButtonBase-root-100 MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" onBlur={[Function (anonymous)]} onFocus={[Function (anonymous)]} onKeyDown={[Function (anonymous)]} onKeyUp={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseDown={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseLeave={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseUp={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchEnd={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchMove={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchStart={[Function (anonymous)]} onContextMenu={[Function (anonymous)]} tabIndex="0" type="button" disabled={false} id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]}>
              <span className="MuiButton-label-75">
                Clear
              </span>
              <NoSsr defer={false} fallback={{...}}>
                <WithStyles(TouchRipple) innerRef={[Function (anonymous)]} center={false}>
                  <TouchRipple center={false} classes={{...}}>
                    <TransitionGroup component="span" enter={true} exit={true} className="MuiTouchRipple-root-103" childFactory={[Function: childFactory]}>
                      <span className="MuiTouchRipple-root-103" />
                    </TransitionGroup>
                  </TouchRipple>
                </WithStyles(TouchRipple)>
              </NoSsr>
            </button>
          </ButtonBase>
        </WithStyles(ButtonBase)>
      </Button>
      <WithStyles(ButtonBase) className="MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" disabled={false} focusRipple={true} focusVisibleClassName="MuiButton-focusVisible-93" id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]} component="button" type="button">
        <ButtonBase className="MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" disabled={false} focusRipple={true} focusVisibleClassName="MuiButton-focusVisible-93" id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]} component="button" type="button" classes={{...}} centerRipple={false} disableRipple={false} disableTouchRipple={false} tabIndex="0">
          <button className="MuiButtonBase-root-100 MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" onBlur={[Function (anonymous)]} onFocus={[Function (anonymous)]} onKeyDown={[Function (anonymous)]} onKeyUp={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseDown={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseLeave={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseUp={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchEnd={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchMove={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchStart={[Function (anonymous)]} onContextMenu={[Function (anonymous)]} tabIndex="0" type="button" disabled={false} id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]}>
            <span className="MuiButton-label-75">
              Clear
            </span>
            <NoSsr defer={false} fallback={{...}}>
              <WithStyles(TouchRipple) innerRef={[Function (anonymous)]} center={false}>
                <TouchRipple center={false} classes={{...}}>
                  <TransitionGroup component="span" enter={true} exit={true} className="MuiTouchRipple-root-103" childFactory={[Function: childFactory]}>
                    <span className="MuiTouchRipple-root-103" />
                  </TransitionGroup>
                </TouchRipple>
              </WithStyles(TouchRipple)>
            </NoSsr>
          </button>
        </ButtonBase>
      </WithStyles(ButtonBase)>
      <ButtonBase className="MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" disabled={false} focusRipple={true} focusVisibleClassName="MuiButton-focusVisible-93" id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]} component="button" type="button" classes={{...}} centerRipple={false} disableRipple={false} disableTouchRipple={false} tabIndex="0">
        <button className="MuiButtonBase-root-100 MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" onBlur={[Function (anonymous)]} onFocus={[Function (anonymous)]} onKeyDown={[Function (anonymous)]} onKeyUp={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseDown={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseLeave={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseUp={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchEnd={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchMove={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchStart={[Function (anonymous)]} onContextMenu={[Function (anonymous)]} tabIndex="0" type="button" disabled={false} id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]}>
          <span className="MuiButton-label-75">
            Clear
          </span>
          <NoSsr defer={false} fallback={{...}}>
            <WithStyles(TouchRipple) innerRef={[Function (anonymous)]} center={false}>
              <TouchRipple center={false} classes={{...}}>
                <TransitionGroup component="span" enter={true} exit={true} className="MuiTouchRipple-root-103" childFactory={[Function: childFactory]}>
                  <span className="MuiTouchRipple-root-103" />
                </TransitionGroup>
              </TouchRipple>
            </WithStyles(TouchRipple)>
          </NoSsr>
        </button>
      </ButtonBase>
      <button className="MuiButtonBase-root-100 MuiButton-root-74 MuiButton-text-76 MuiButton-flat-79 MuiButton-sizeSmall-97 MessageItem-cardclearbutton-1 MuiCardActions-action-73" onBlur={[Function (anonymous)]} onFocus={[Function (anonymous)]} onKeyDown={[Function (anonymous)]} onKeyUp={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseDown={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseLeave={[Function (anonymous)]} onMouseUp={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchEnd={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchMove={[Function (anonymous)]} onTouchStart={[Function (anonymous)]} onContextMenu={[Function (anonymous)]} tabIndex="0" type="button" disabled={false} id="button-messageitem-1" onClick={[Function: onClick]}>
        <span className="MuiButton-label-75">
          Clear
        </span>
        <NoSsr defer={false} fallback={{...}}>
          <WithStyles(TouchRipple) innerRef={[Function (anonymous)]} center={false}>
            <TouchRipple center={false} classes={{...}}>
              <TransitionGroup component="span" enter={true} exit={true} className="MuiTouchRipple-root-103" childFactory={[Function: childFactory]}>
                <span className="MuiTouchRipple-root-103" />
              </TransitionGroup>
            </TouchRipple>
          </WithStyles(TouchRipple)>
        </NoSsr>
      </button>
```

(Material-ui puts lots of code just for a simple button, right?)

I also tried `wrapper.find("button");` and nothing, no matter what I always get the error message: `Method “html” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your test ? Do you use `enzyme.shallow` or `enzyme.mount` ?

Comment: @SimonBruneaud Hi Simon, I updated the question with the test code!

Comment: For Full DOM rendering you can use `mount(<MessageItem ...>)` - it may fix your issue

Comment: @SimonBruneaud no, it didn't work. I'm using material-ui and I also tested `shallow = createShallow();` and nothing.

Comment: Did you try to debug `console.log(wrapper.debug());` - it seems that the wrapper doesn't contains the DOM at all

Comment: Yes, it shows more than one element, I bet this is the problem. I updated the question with the output from `wrapper.debug()`.

Comment: @SimonBruneaud please see the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonBruneaud using `mount(<MessageItem ...>)` fixed the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice, happy to hear that :)